# Solve numerical equation quickly

Tags: python, numerical-methods, solver, scipy-optimize

I am using `scipy.optimize.newton_krylov` to solve the problem described below.
However, it is rather slow (this done for thousands of points). Even if my initial guess is very close to the solution it is slow. This makes me wonder if there is a better way to do this.

What is the quickest way to find a 3D point `(x,y,z)=pvec` that fulfills the three equations el1, el2 and el3 (e.g. minimize the norm of the vector [el1,el2,el3]).

```py
sr1=np.sqrt(np.sum( (pvec - p2)**2 )) 
sr2=np.sqrt(np.sum( (pvec - p1)**2 )) 

el1=(sr1 + sr2)/(2.0*scalar1) - 1.0
el2=np.sum( (pvec/scalar2)**2 ) - 1.0
el3=np.dot(v1,(pvec - p1) )/(sr1*scalar3) + \
    np.dot(v2,(pvec - p2) )/(sr2*scalar3) - 1.0
```

Answer (score 0):

I would try the different methods mentioned [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.root.html)

In my experience the default method "hybr" works very well.